# Windows 7 says "Logged On" after booting and stays at the logon screen

Tags: windows-7, login

We have some info-screens at the company and they all have auto-login enabled. However, one screen started to act up in a weird way where it brings up an error message saying the user has already logged in.

I tried removing all auto-login Registry keys again but no matter what I try the account is still mysteriously logging in at boot even tho it's not going to the desktop of that user. It'll simply stay at the user select screen but beneath the user picture it says "logged on". When I then proceed to login by hand it will indeed let me, but it's acting like I wasn't even logged in to begin with since all the programs aren't started yet.

I never had this happening before and tried most of the fixed I found online already, with obviously no luck... Do you guys have some ideas left still?

Comment: "Do you guys have some ideas left still?" Not when you haven't told us what you have tried already...

Comment: Yes. Please tell us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I managed to fix it myself quite some time ago but forgot to update this question :)

Anyways, it wasn't directly Windows own fault. We use Novell and ZenWorks which were causing troubles, for some reason the installation of one of them got corrupted and prevented a proper login. After un- and reinstalling both the auto-login worked again.